# Angular2 asynchronous http request

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have an `http` request function here `ingredients.service`

```
searchIngredients(query:string) {
    let search = this.ingredientsUrl + "?q=" + query
    return this.http.get(search, {headers:this.headers})
        .map(res=>res.json());
}
```

My html code is as follows...

```
<input [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
         [typeahead]="dataSource"
         (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
         (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event)"
         (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
         typeaheadOptionsLimit="10"
         typeaheadOptionField="name"
         typeaheadAsync="false"
         placeholder="Search for Ingredient"
         class="form-control">
```

this uses ngx-bootstrap to provide typeahead functionality to my app. Currently when I type in the input, it calls `searchIngredients` which updates `ingredients` so that the typeahead input can update information in the dropdown menu. However, since the call to `searchIngredients` is asynchronous, it doesnt update `ingredients` in time for it to be displayed in the dropdown menu.

```
public getIngredientsAsObservable(query: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log("observable")
    this.query = query
    this.searchIngredients()

    return Observable.of(
      this.ingredients
    );
}
```

how can I run

```
this.searchIngredients()

return Observable.of(
  this.ingredients
);
```

so that I only return the observable once `this.ingredients` is updated?

my `searchIngredients` function is as follows

```
searchIngredients(){
    this.ingredientService.searchIngredients(this.query)
      .subscribe(
        data=>{
          this.ingredients = data.results
          console.log("Success")
        },
        error=>{
          console.log(error)
        },
        ()=>{
          console.log("Request Complete")
          console.log(this.ingredients)
        }
      );
}
```

Comment: Create a plnkr, your question is not very clear in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in your code, your service returns observable:

```
public searchIngredients(query:string) {
    let search = this.ingredientsUrl + "?q=" + query
    return this.http.get(search, {headers:this.headers})
        .map(res=>res.json());
}
```

In your component you can just wire it up to the field:

```
export class YourComponent {
    public ingredients;

    ngOnInit() {
         this.ingredients = this.searchIngredients("");
    }

    searchIngredients(){
         this.ingredients = this.searchIngredients(this.query);
    }
}
```

Comment: So the way you are saying it, my function will only return ingredients once ingredients is actually populated from the get request? It has to be able to update the ingredients upon every keystroke. Currently, it will show search results from the last keystroke and not the current one, which isn't too useful

Comment: What do you mean by 'every keystroke'? Every input from <input> tag?

Comment: Yeah the main typeahead functions are called every time the value of the input changes